# java - hibernate invalid configuration exception

Tags: java, hibernate

I was trying changing !DOCTYPE but still not working

My Test.java

```
import com.serwis.model.User;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;


/**
 * Created by Jodanpotasu on 2016-07-17.
 */
public class TEST {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure(); //with configure("hibernate.cfx.xml still not working
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry
                = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();

        // builds a session factory from the service registry
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);



        try{
            User user = new User(1,"login","password","mail",null);

            Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(user);

        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("blad");
        } finally {
            System.out.println("zrobiono");
        }





    }
}
```

My hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration xmlns="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-configuration">
    <session-factory>
        <!-- JDBC connection settings -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:9001</property>
        <property name="connection.username">sa</property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>

        <!--https://www.progress.com/jdbc/resources/tutorials/connection-pooling/connection -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- SQL DIALECT -->
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</property>

        <!-- SHOW SQL OUTPUT -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>



    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

and the output from console

> Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: invalid
>   configuration     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2160)
>     at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2077)
>     at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2056)
>     at com.serwis.TEST.main(TEST.java:17)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
>   Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 6; columnNumber:
>   87; Attribute "xmlns" must be declared for element type
>   "hibernate-configuration".    at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:396)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:284)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.addDTDDefaultAttrsAndValidate(XMLDTDValidator.java:1253)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleStartElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:1917)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:742)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:380)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:614)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3135)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:880)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:118)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
>     at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:465)  at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2157)
>     ... 8 more
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Where i am doing mistake?

Comment: Why dont you just remove the doctype as a start. It is a non mandatory attribute.

Comment: Actually it is complaining about line 6 which corresponds to the xmlns element. You can remove the namespace I dont think it will complain about it. It is again non mandatory.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the namespace element (xmlns) from the

```
 <hibernate-configuration
xmlns="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-configuration">
```

Comment: It almost works, now i have another bug with connection! :D Intellij added me that one.

Comment: Hah, well at least you are one step further.